# How to resolve target redefinition problem in diamond subproject dependency?

Tags: cmake

There are two libs **libA** and **libB** depending on **libBase** and including it into build process with

`add_subdirectory(../libBase build/libBase)`

Everything works when they are build separately. But when project **prj** wants to include everything into its build process:

```
add_subdirectory(../libA build/libA)
add_subdirectory(../libB build/libB)
```

Then cmake complaints about target redefinition:

```
add_library cannot create target "libBase" because another target with the same name already exists.
```

How to make such project (building all dependences in one step) correct? Is it achievable with `add_subdirectory` or sth else should be used to add dependencies?

Comment: There are many questions on Stack Overflow about handling diamond dependencies in CMake: https://www.google.com/search?q=cmake+diamond+dependency+site:stackoverflow.com. Have you checked them?

Answer (score 1):

Found it: [include_guard()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_guard.html?highlight=include_guard) since cmake 3.10